Cannot build with style dictionary getting "TransformStream is not defined" error
i'm trying to use figma tokens and therefore to transform them to scss files with style-dictionary package.
however, when i'm trying to build using the cli command style-dictinary build this is the error i'm getting:
/AppData/Roaming/nvm/v14.15.5/node_modules/style-dictionary/node_modules/@zip.js/zip.js/lib/core/streams/crc32-stream.js:33        
class Crc32Stream extends TransformStream {
                          ^

ReferenceError: TransformStream is not defined
    at file:///C:/Users/ILPETDAOM/AppData/Roaming/nvm/v14.15.5/node_modules/style-dictionary/node_modules/@zip.js/zip.js/lib/core/streams/crc32-stream.js:33:27

I've tried to reinstall the package,
i've tried to run npm i inside the node-module package...
nothing works..
anyone has an idea?

You can fix this issue by including web-streams-polyfill in your project. It is a polyfill of the "Web Streams" API, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-streams-polyfill
